# How to hide system tables of oracle in sde connection?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial

I connected to oracle 11g r2 with ArcGIS 10.2 using SDE connection. The connection is ok but in the connection i see system tables of  APEX_030200 and other  schemas. Same question is in the [Geonet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/3458) but nobody answer the question in the forum. How can i hide system tables in sde user ?

Comment: The only way to hide tables granted public SELECT access, besides removing the public grants, is to modify ArcGIS. I believe this was done at 10.2.1 or 10.2.2.

Comment: But when i want to revoke select grant from these tables, i encounter to an  error "cannot REVOKE privileges you did not grant" .I think this means that these tables didn't  grant select previusly

Comment: No, that just means the user you revoked as doesn't have the permission to do so (is not the owner or DBA).

Comment: @wetland ,  I not sure about this. But you may have be able to revoke read permissions on all \*APEX\* tables from sde user. However you need the system (or apex owner) privilege to do this.